# Derving parameters of linear fit by minimizing cost function

Tags: optimization, linear-regression

For a linear regression task I have the basic cost function $E(a,b) = \sum_{i=1}^m(y_i - f(x_i))^2$, where $f(x) = ax+b$.

I'm now looking for an analytical solution without Matrix notation. I did the partial derivatives w.r.t. $a$ and $b$, but I think I've made a mistake somewhere.
My derived expression for $a$ and $b$ respectively are:

$a = \frac{\sum y_ix_i - b\sum x_i}{\sum x_i^2}$

$b = \sum y_i - a \sum x_i$

I've put $b$ into $a$ and got:
$a = \frac{\sum y_ix_i - \sum y_i \sum x_i}{\sum x_i^2 - (\sum x_i)^2}$

I've coded and testet that in Python, but I only got the correct results if I would change $a$ and $b$ to:

$a = \frac{m \sum y_ix_i - b\sum x_i}{m\sum x_i^2}$

$b = \frac{\sum y_i - a \sum x_i}{m}$

which doesn't make sense to me at all.
I hope somebody can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already figured out, you are missing factor $m$. To find this, simply do a simpler case where you skip the linear term $ax$. The derivative w.r.t $b$ is $\sum_{i=1}^m 2(y_i-b) = \sum_{i=1}^m 2y_i - 2mb$ which gives you $b = (\sum_{i=1}^m y_i) / m$ i.e. the average value, while you currently get the sum.

Comment: wow, I totally missed that $\sum_{i=1}^m x_i ... + b^2$ does not equal to $b^2 + \sum_{i=1}^m x_i ...$, but should be $\sum_{i=1}^m b^2 + \sum_{i=1}^m x_i ... = mb +  \sum_{i=1}^m x_i ...$.

Thanks a lot for the very fast help, you saved my day!